# How to give Custom color to the value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have many tablix in report, User need all negative values in red color,
i tried with iif condition at the color option, but it going to consume lot of time since i need to modify each and every cell

Can any body suggest me is there any way to give color to cell without going to the color option

Thanks 
it will be a great help to me

Comment: select the detail row. press f4 for properties. copy paste the iif condition in the font color. DONE!

Comment: Hello Bhupesh, my condition is different for each cell, can not select all time

Comment: how many columns you need to add this red font color?

Comment: There are many, i can say more than 1000

Answer (score 1):

To make copying the formula easier, use the built-in `Me` reference, which accesses the current object (being the cell):

```
=IIF(Me.Value < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

Now you can just copy and paste that into the Font.Color property without having to edit the expression for the field value.

Comment: Hello  Chirs, Thanks for the reply,How to give reference, it may be the basic question but i do not know

Comment: `Me` is the reference - it refers to the current object (cell, textbox, etc). Just use the formula in the answer, it should work as is

Comment: Sorry i did not get, Can you please provide me the example, my cell value is sum(Value) (The expression is pretty long) , if i wanna give color for this i need to go to color option in the properties then the iif condition like iif(sum(Value)<0,"red",'Black") here, where i can include reference, Thanks

Comment: `Me` references the cell so `Me.Value` is the value for the expression in your cell; i.e. `Sum(Value)`. Just use the exact expression from my answer in your cell.